# Why doesn't the value hold outside the method scope?

Tags: ruby

I declare a variable inside an `if` statement which doesn't exist outside of that scope.

```
def calculate_concurrent_product_quantity(other_job_with_product, job_product)
  other_job_with_product.job_products.map do |prod|
    if prod.product_id == job_product.product_id
      @stuff = prod
      raise
    end
    @stuff #here it equals nil?!
  end
end
```

If I raise the method here, the variable `@stuff` holds the correct values inside the `if` statement.

```
@stuff
#=> #<JobProduct id: 380, job_id: 90, product_id: 363, quantity: 2, frozen_cache: {}, created_at: "2014-08-14 13:18:02", updated_at: "2014-08-14 13:18:02">
```

but anything outside of that it doesn't work. Why is this happening? I tried to use the `select` method instead of doing it like this, but I get an error saying the method is private.

Comment: You yourself said the magic word: scope.  Scope is all about the range in which variables are defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it should probably be:

```
@stuff = other_job_with_product.job_products.find {|prod| prod.product_id == job_product.product_id}
```

The most likely reason of the behaviour you describe is that you are in the loop. `@stuff` is assigned with a value only for the matching element and is not assigned until then. When you raise where your comment is, you are raising always on the first iteration of the loop, when `@stuff` is likely to be still nil. Raising inside `if` raises only when `@stuff` is found and assigned.